# função so retorna promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Estou estudando sobre JS com Node e Express. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que ira consultar dados do auxilio emergencial através da API publica disponibilizada pelo GOV.

Tenho uma função que retorna os dados JSON de um determinado CPF, ela funciona normal se passado somente 1 CPF.
Quando tento chamar essa função atreves de outra função, ela somente retorna um erro devido ao `await`.

Função que faz a consulta na api:

```
async function getConsultaBeneficiario(data) {
  var obj = [];
  try {
    var url = `http://www.transparencia.gov.br/api-de-dados/auxilio-emergencial-por-cpf-ou-nis?codigoBeneficiario=${data.cpf}&pagina=1`;
    var opt = {
      headers: {
        'chave-api-dados': 'minhaChave'
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.get(url, opt);
    if (response.data == '' || response.data == null) {
      obj = {
        cpf: `${data.cpf}`,
        nome: `${data.nome}`,
        Message: 'sem informação',
      };

      return obj;

    }

    obj = response.data;
    return obj;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      'Error - erro na consulta do CPF - function getConsultaBeneficiario(cpf)'
    );
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Nesta função eu faço a chamada a função acima, passando atraves de loop, varios cpfs para consulta:

```
async function getListaBeneficioJson() {
  var listaBenef = [];
  var jsonBenef = `${__dirname}/json/file.json`;
  var data = [];
  try {
    var benef = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonBenef, 'utf-8'));

    var resut = benef.map((item) => {
      console.log('chamando funcao getConsultaBeneficiario'); 
      data.push(await getConsultaBeneficiario(item)); // erro se da por essa linha
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return listaBenef;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO:

```
const getListaBeneficioJson = async () => {
  var listaBenef = [];
  var jsonBenef = `${__dirname}/json/file.json`;
  try {
    var benef = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonBenef, 'utf-8'));

    benef = benef.map(async (user) => {
      const datas = await getConsultaBeneficiario(user);
      // console.log(datas);
      return datas;
    });

    listaBenef = (async () => {
      listaBenef = await Promise.all(benef);
      // console.log(listaBenef);
      //console.log('fim da lista');
      return listaBenef;
    })();

    return listaBenef;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```